# Browser detection using Zend Framework or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework, mootools, cross-browser

I am creating an application that requires the ability to upload large files. I have chosen to use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object as using this I can report back to the user the progress.

Not surprisingly IE doesn't support this so I am having to fall back to Flash. What is the best way of detecting for IE 7/8/9+ using Zend Framework? I am loading in the other assets as per needed via the indexAction method in each controller. For example:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->stepnumber = 1;
    $this->view->stepintro = 'Upload your photo.';
    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/assets/js/fileuploader.js');
}
```

Now, in one of my pages I have already done some form of browser detection (for some `canvas` work):

```
public function indexAction()
{

    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    $this->view->stepnumber = 5;
    $this->view->stepintro = 'Select your cut out detail.';

    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i', $u_agent)) {
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/assets/js/excanvas.js');
    } else {
        $this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/assets/js/mootools/mootools-canvas-lib/mcl-min.js');
    }      

    $this->view->headScript()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl().'/assets/js/frank/pentool.js');

    $image = $this->uploadsDb->getImage();    

    $data = $this->nodedataDb->getNodedata($image->id);

    $this->view->image = $image;
    $this->view->nodeData = $data;


}
```

I am not too sold on this method though, I would rather check using Javascript as this would be more futureproof (I think). But how would I go about using Javasript within my ZF layout.phtml so I'm only loading the Javascript that I require? Cutting down on calls to the server.

Any help is much appreciated.

SOLUTION:

I have decided to use YepNope:

```
yepnope({  
  test : "FormData" in window,
  yep  : 'normal.js',  
  nope : 'flashupload.js'  
});
```

Comment: Don't browser detect, feature detect! http://modernizr.com/

Comment: I think you should be checking clientside whether the browser supports the features needed, not whether the browser is ie.

Comment: Ok, if I check clientside then how do I elegantly only download the required JS? With feature detection I have to download everything, no?

Comment: Modernizr doesn't check for FormData

Comment: Can't you use YepNope with Modernizr to perform additional checks?

Comment: What test would it be for yepnope?

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking for a easy way to append css style sheets / javascript files for IE only browsers, you can use the conditional comments argument, as such:

For any file besides css stylesheets:

```
$this->view->headLink()->appendFile($this->view->baseUrl() . '/media/js/core.js', 'text/javascript', array('conditional' => 'IE');
```

Note the `array('conditional' => 'IE')` argument.

For appending stylesheet files, the function arguments are a little different:

```
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->view->baseUrl() . '/media/css/core.css', 'all', 'IE');
```

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headstyle

Comment: That's great :) Never knew that but have decided to take the feature detection route.

Answer (score -2):

you can add a javascript in case the feature is not available (i am using jquery for short syntax);

```
if(typeof featureA == "undefined"){
    $("<script/>").attr({
        "src" : "/assets/featurea.js",
        "type": "text/javascript"
    }).appendTo($("head").eq(0));
}
```

you can use the same for other features so you don't have to download'em all.